# What was fixed in Xcode 5.1 or llvm3.4svn?

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, labview, llvm-clang

Some weeks ago, I had a nasty problem using a dynamic library with LabView. The problem occurred when LabView tried to load a dynamic library written in C++. An excerpt of the segmentation fault that I encountered was:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/National Instruments/*/LabVIEW.app/Contents/MacOS/LabVIEW
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000002fe3000 [ 47.9M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/National Instruments/*/LabVIEW.app/Contents/MacOS/LabVIEW

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x99bf83e7 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$sse42 + 215
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x939e5cc2 fgets + 227
2   com.ni.labview                      0x01962d6c ReadExternalLibExports(unsigned char const*, CPStr***, _LStrArray***) + 812
3   com.ni.labview                      0x003c9df0 UpdateFuncList(ObjectHeap*, long, LIBFUNCDATA**, long) + 400
4   com.ni.labview                      0x003ca1a0 SetupLibFuncDlg(ObjectHeap*, BasicObject*, unsigned long*, LIBFUNCDATA**, long, long*) + 592
5   com.ni.labview                      0x003c1195 LoadLibDialog(ObjectHeap*, BasicObject*, long, long*) + 85
... and much more stack information.
```

I tried to narrow down this problem for some days, without luck. Somewhere I read that the `_platform_memmove...` was related to a 32/64bit issues, which seemed possible to me, since I am developing in a 64bit system (Mac OSX mavericks).

To my surprise, I did an update of Xcode this week that solved the problem. But there is nothing worst than an invisible enemy, rather than a vanquished one. In other words, I still don't know what caused this segmentation fault, and why it's gone.

My question is: what was fixed (I presume in LLVM-3.4) that would be related to this kind of errors? The release notes do not provide enough details for me to answer this question myself, of course.